# c++ beginner - class and passing

Tags: c++, class

I am trying to print these polynomials but I can not seem to print what I want.
If my polynomial was `1*x + 2*x^2` then output would be `4*x`. I want `1 + 4*x`.

```
void Poly :: derivative (){
  term *z ;
  if ( term_t == NULL)
    return ;
  term *temp1;
  temp1 = term_t;
  while ( temp1 != NULL ){
   if ( term_t == NULL ){
     term_t = new term ;
      z = term_t ;
    }
    else{
      z -> next = new term ;
      z = z -> next ;
    }
    z-> coef = temp1 -> coef * temp1 -> exp;
    z-> exp = temp1 -> exp - 1;
    temp1 = temp1 -> next;
  }
  term_t=z;
}
```

I have a class `poly` and a struct `term_t` with `coef` and `exp` in them.

Comment: What does your `Poly::derivative()` method have to do with printing your poly? The code snippet you presented doesn't have anything to do with your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I'd have the derivative function return a Poly, rather than modify the existing one. Something like this

```
Poly derivative() {
    Poly res;
    Term *temp1 = this->term_t;
    while (temp1 != NULL) {
      int nexp = temp1->getExp() - 1;
      int ncoef = temp1->getCoef() * temp1->getExp();
      res.add(new Term(ncoef, nexp));
      temp1 = temp1->getNext();
    }
    return res;
}
```

As for the printing problem though, yeah, you haven't provided enough of your code to really know what's going on. So, I wrote my own... this is how I'd approach the problem. First a Term class like this

```
class Term {
public:
  Term(int coef, int exp) {
    this->coef = coef;
    this->exp = exp;
    this->next = NULL;
  }

  std::string toString() const {
    std::stringstream ss;
    if (this->coef == 0) return "0";
    if (this->exp == 0) ss << this->coef;
    else {
      if (this->coef != 1) ss << this->coef;
      ss << "x";
      if (this->exp != 1) ss << "^" << this->exp;
    }
    return ss.str();
  }

  int getCoef() const {return this->coef;}
  int getExp() const {return this->exp;}
  Term* getNext() const {return this->next;}
  void setNext(Term* n) {this->next = n;}

private:
  int coef;
  int exp;
  Term* next;
};
```

then a Poly class like this

```
class Poly {
public:
  Poly() {
    this->term_t = NULL;
  }
  void add(Term* nt) {
    if (this->term_t == NULL) {
      this->term_t = nt;
    } else {
      Term* t = this->term_t;
      while(t->getNext() != NULL) t = t->getNext();
      t->setNext(nt);
    }
  }
  std::string toString() const {
    std::stringstream ss;
    Term* t = this->term_t;
    while (t != NULL) {
      ss << t->toString();
      if (t->getNext() != NULL) ss << " + ";
      t = t->getNext();
    }
    return ss.str();
  }

  Poly derivative() {
    Poly res;
    Term *temp1 = this->term_t;
    while (temp1 != NULL){
      int nexp = temp1->getExp() - 1;
      int ncoef = temp1->getCoef() * temp1->getExp();
      res.add(new Term(ncoef, nexp));
      temp1 = temp1->getNext();
    }
    return res;
  }

private :
  Term* term_t;
};
```

That'd leave the memory management of the Term objects up to the class users, but you could also write a destructor for the Poly class that deletes them.